# How to better utilise CPUs with nodejs jobserver

Tags: node.js

Given below is the simple implementation of nodejs clusters, where child processes are created to fully utilise the CPU cores.

```
const cluster = require('cluster'),
      http    = require('http'),
      numCPUs = 4;

if (cluster.isMaster) {
    for (var i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++)
        cluster.fork()
} else {
   function1()
   function2()
   function3()
}
```

> What I have is a Jobserver which processes variable counts of jobs.
>   ie, executes different independent functions once in specific time
>   intervals.

**The above cluster model cannot be used because I don't want each of the forked child to execute all the functions.**

> How do I distribute these functions among all the forked child, so
>   that each child executes a set of functions and all of my CPU cores
>   are utilised ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check `worker.id` to run different functions for each worker, this is documented [here](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_worker_id).

```js
const cluster = require('cluster'),
      http    = require('http'),
      numCPUs = 4;

if (cluster.isMaster) {
    for (var i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++)
        cluster.fork()
} else {
   const { id } = cluster.worker;

   console.log('I am worker #' + id);

   switch (id) {
       case 0: {
         function1();
       }
       case 1: {
         function2();
       }
       case 2: {
         function3();
       }
   }
}
```

**EDIT:** Another solution

```js
const cluster = require('cluster'),
      http    = require('http'),
      numCPUs = 4;

const coreFunction = {
  0: () => { // core 1 functions
    function1();
    // could add multiple functions per core etc;
  },

  1: () => { // core 2 functions
    function2();
    function22();
  }
};

if (cluster.isMaster) {
    for (var i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++)
        cluster.fork()
} else {
   const { id } = cluster.worker;

   console.log('I am worker #' + id);

   coreFunction[id]();
}
```

**EDIT:** Another solution #2

```js
const cluster = require('cluster'),
      http    = require('http'),
      os = require('os');

const numCPUs = os.cpus().length;

const functions = [
    function1,
    function2,
    function3,
    function4,
    function5,
];

function chunk(arr, n) {
    return arr.slice(0,(arr.length+n-1)/n|0).
       map(function(c,i) { return arr.slice(n*i,n*i+n); });
}

const functionChunks = chunk(functions, numCPUs);

if (cluster.isMaster) {
    for (var i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++)
        cluster.fork()
} else {
   const { id } = cluster.worker;

   console.log('I am worker #' + id);

   functionChunks[id].forEach(function (func) {
       func();
   })
}
```

Comment: I have come across this method. But, in my case the number of cores and the number of functions are be dynamic.

Comment: Maybe you could use something like: https://github.com/alexgorbatchev/fork-promise

Comment: @AkashDathan i updated the answer with an edit, what about this solution?

Comment: In the second case, the cpu cores cannot be dynamic.

Comment: @AkashDathan so lets say that you have 4 cores and 16 functions to run, you want that these 16 functions would be assigned to each core so there is 4 per core?

Comment: @AkashDathan It would be possible to have a array of functions and method that splits all these tasks by the number of cores, i will add another example